# How to hande premature nils in variadic objective-c functions?

Tags: objective-c, variadic-functions

Say I have the following, very contrived, set up:

```objectivec
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
+ (void) doSomethingToVariableArguments:(SomeClass*) someObject, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
- (void) doSomething;
@end

@implementation SomeClass

+ (void) doSomethingToVariableArguments:(SomeClass*) someObject, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION {
    [someObject doSomething];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, someObject);
    SomeClass* next;
    while ((next = va_arg(args, SomeClass*))) {
        [next doSomething];
    }
    va_end(args);
    return;
}

- (void) doSomething {
    // do something
    return;
}
```

Now we assume that somewhere, there is a call `[SomeClass doSomethingToVariableArguments:obj1, obj2, obj3, nil];`.

What happens if, for some reason, `obj2` is `nil`?

Well, `- doSomething` is only called for `obj1`, since we encounter a nil and assume the argument-list has terminated. `obj3` is completely ignored, and e.g. fails to update.

Is there any way, besides checking if the arguments are `nil`, to catch this and maybe issue a warning, or even raise an error?

Comment: @Willeke: Could be. Using a sentinel different from nil would solve this. But it's of course not as pretty

Comment: BTW, IMO, The bot shouldn't have closed this question, I didn't mean to close it on my own.

Comment: Bot didn't close the question, I accepted it as a suitable answer (I honestly don't believe there is a way of doing this while keeping nil as the sentinel)

Comment: If nil is the only sentinel, then no.  If you want to add an argument before the varargs which is a count which could be iterated instead of looking for nil, it could work.  You could try to pass NSNulls on the caller to stand in for nil (```[SomeClass doSomethingToVariableArguments:obj1 ?: NSNull.null, obj2 ?: NSNull.null, obj3 ?: NSNull.null, nil]```), and the called method could then check for NSNull and avoid calling doSomething in that case.